# QGraphicsProxyWidget не отрисовывается на сцене

Tags: qt, qt5

Исследую добавление виджетов на сцену, в книге все описано крайне не подробно (там только пример и пару абзацев текста). Вот моя попытка:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsScale>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsProxyWidget* wgt;
    QTransform transform;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

и реализация

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);  //вот они наши сцены
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    QPushButton btn("Пуск");
    QGraphicsProxyWidget* wgt = scene->addWidget(&btn);
    wgt->resize(100,100);
    QTransform transform = wgt->transform();
    transform.translate(100,100);
    transform.rotate(-45,Qt::YAxis);
    transform.scale(8,2);
    wgt->setTransform(transform);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Вроде все по руководству, но на сцене пустота. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Объект btn создаётся в стеке и тут же удаляется. Замените его на указатель

Comment: Простите, мне не понятно. Разве вот это QGraphicsProxyWidget* wgt = scene->addWidget(&btn); не передача объекта btn по ссылке ?

Comment: нет это не передача, наверное на скриптовых языках раньше тренировались? удивляюсь что у вас программа не падает, сделайте new для btn

Comment: Вы правы, раньше я работа с PowerShel. Оператор, new сработал, весьма признателен. Кстати пример взят из книги, но там этот момент не объясняется.